# SQl Azure Switching Clusterd and Non Clustered Index

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, database-indexes

I have two indexes on my table:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IXAddrbookCrtDtm] ON [dbo].[Addrbook]
(
     [AbkOrgGrpID] ASC,
     [AddrbookID] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addrbook]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PKAddrbook_New]
      PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
      (
       [AbkOrgGrpID] ASC,
       [AddrbookID] ASC
      )
      WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
            SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
            ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
           ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

I need to have just one Clustered Primary Key Index instead of above two. Dropping and recreating the tables is not an option.

Is there something like

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IXAddrbookCrtDtm ON
    Addrbook(AbkOrgGrpID,AddrbookID)
    PRIMARY KEY  WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

so that I can then drop the non-clustered index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop both the indexes and create new one ,instead of dropping the tabel.

steps involved..

Drop index

> drop index IXAddrbookCrtDtm on [dbo].[Addrbook]

Drop constraint

> alter table [dbo].[Addrbook]
>   drop constraint PKAddrbook_New

Create new Primary key

> alter table [dbo].[Addrbook] add primary key (AbkOrgGrpID,AddrbookID)

Comment: Will Azure SQL DB allow me to Drop the Clustered Index without recreating the table?

Comment: You dont need to drop table

Comment: with V12, and if you are on it,it is not mandatory:http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/indexes-azure-sql-database-v12